# How to show preloader inside button instead text Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use Angular JS library **ngActivityIndicator**.
I tried to show preloader inside element `div` instead text when button is pushed:

```
<div ng-activity-indicator="CircledDark">
    <div ng-click="Add();" class="btn shareBtn">
        <div ng-view></div>
        <span>Text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I posted `<div ng-view></div>` inside and have added directive `ng-activity-indicator="CircledDark"` to parent element.

When I click button, I call function that display preloader:

```
$activityIndicator.startAnimating();
```

But preloader is created outside of button:

```
<div ng-show="AILoading" class="ai-circled ai-indicator ai-dark-spin"></div>
```

This is official documantation, from here I have taken example:
https://github.com/voronianski/ngActivityIndicator#directive

How to show preloader inside button instead text Angular JS?

Comment: Please reproduce your issue using a platform like [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/). It's hard to tell what's wrong with just those snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only solution is to separate your `ng-view` and button, at least they do something similar in their [sample](http://labs.voronianski.com/ngActivityIndicator.js/) page. So, in your markup you could do something like this:

```
<div ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-default" ng-activity-indicator="CircledDark">
  <span ng-show="!AILoading">Add</span>
</div>
<div ng-view ng-show="!AILoading">{{ delayedText }}</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.delayedText = "";
$scope.add = function() {
  $activityIndicator.startAnimating();
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.delayedText = "Here we are!";
    $activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
  }, 3000);
};
```

Here is full [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dnt5RIiHryZLD1PrA1j7?p=preview), you can play with CSS a little so the size of the button won't change when text is replaced by icon.